# Shorter File Names For Controller CI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-restserver

Are there any libraries or helpers that can allow me to have a class ControllerCommonDashboard which extends CI_Controller but have the file name just be dashboard.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ControllerCommonDashboard extends MX_Controller {
}
```

At the moment I have to make file name same as the class name.

Not sure how to best use these functions to get what I am after

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
$this->router->fetch_module();
```

Comment: I don't beleieve there is, But why would you want it shorter?

Comment: Looks nicer in the files if just have dashboard.php

Comment: That router class you posted is used to get the current class and method from a URI, not exactly what you want.

You can display shorter names on the URI but you can't change the name.

You can however instantiate a new instance yourself(I guess), instead of having it auto load, load it up yourself

`$this->dashboard = new ControllerCommonDashboard`   I never tried it, But it might work

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer: No.

#### No such library or helper.

## Long answer:

Don't try to do such hardcore stuff.

I can provide you some solutions.

### Solution 1:

Since the long ugly name is ControllerCommonDashboard, there must be some controllers like ControllerAdminDashboard.

You can create 'admin' and 'common' folder in 'controllers' folder. Then you create '/admin/dashborad.php' and '/admin/dashboard.php' for them. Vist url '/common/dashboard' or '/admin/dashboard' would work for this.

### Solution 2:

You think the uri for users is too ugly?

Just route them!

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

add this in route.php

```
$route['dashboard'] = "controllercommondashboard";
```

Then everyone can visit uri with '/dashboard/action' on your site.

### Solution 3:

Remove the 'Controller' from 'ControllerCommonDashboard', just 'CommonDashboard' would be much beaitiful and simple for both yourself and visitors who go to your site!